# Center An SVG Group Dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg, alignment

I'm struggling to understand how to center this `SVG` group `<g class="templateParent">`. It seems to start from close to the center of the screen, even though there is no transformation being applied to it. That is actually what I want to do dynamically, i.e. center to the screen.

http://jsbin.com/takuyevaxa/edit?html,output

Code :

```
<svg class="svg">
  <g class="templateParent">
    <g class="templateGroup">
      <path fill="" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" d="M245.611,155.598c-4,1.667-5.479,5.559-7.813,7.559s-28.292,40.538-31.909,46.569c-2.999,5-52.999,52-52.999,52l-11.668-13c0,0,35.254-49.74,36.667-52c3.333-5.334,21.081-26.883,25.667-34.334c6.158-10.008,21.176-54.66,40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563,104.376,250.385,149.451,245.611,155.598z" class="left extend clipPath"></path>
      <path fill="" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" d="M134.723,254.35L140.89 240.058 158.89 259.059 146.348 267.725z M134.723,254.35L137.89 241.058 139.89 241.725" class="left extend restrict"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

So my question is why is the group `.templateParent` not starting from the top left position of SVG canvas? & subsequently, how do I center the group?

Comment: Figured out, its the x & y values on the svg which are affecting the position. So they need to be accounted for.

Comment: You can't position groups.  They are just a virtual container for their children.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yes, you cant, if you are using x & y. You can transform it though.

Comment: Yes. Although technically you are really adding a common transform to all the group's children.  But the outcome is the same.